# Spring Security - CouchDB

Tags: spring-security

I want to write Authorization used the Spring Security. Users data will be saved in the couchDB. I have problem with make it possible access to methods.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    @Transactional
    public void deleteDriver(Driver driver) {
        dataService.deleteDrivers(driver);
    }..
```

This annotation `@PreAuthorize` not worked. I wrote:

```
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" jsr250-annotations="enabled">
```

into Aplication-context-security.xml

Comment: Can you please rephrase? I find it rather hard to see what is being asked.

Comment: Any good tutorial to implement Spring Security Core to  CouchDB ?

Comment: @code4jhon if you still need it I answer the question and it might help :)

Answer (score 0):

I bet you already solve your problem, but maybe this can help someone else...

**1- Configuration of the app**

You need to add your own implementation of **UserDetailsService**.

```
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration {
...
    @Bean
    public UserSecurityService userSecurityService() {
        return new UserSecurityService();
    }
...
}
```

**2- User Entity**

```
public class CustomUserDetail extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User {

    public CustomUserDetail(String username, String password, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, authorities);
    }
}
```

**3- UserRepository**

```
@Component
public class UserRepository extends CouchDbRepositorySupport<User> {
        ...
        @View( name = "findUserByUsername", map = "function(doc) { if (doc.docType == 'User' ) emit( doc.username, doc._id ) }")
        public User findUserByUsername(String username) {
            return queryViewReturnSingleEntity("findUserByUsername",username);          
        }
        ...
}
```

4- Implementation of **UserDetailsService**, UserSecurityService

```
public class UserSecurityService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException
    {
        //Spring user
        UserDetails userDetails = null;

        //CouchDB Object
        User user = userRepo.getByUsername(username);

        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        String rol = user.getRol();
        grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(rol));

        if(user != null){
            //Spring user implementation
            userDetails = new CustomUserDetail(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), grantedAuths);
        }

        if (userDetails == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }

        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

5- Finally, you have to extend **GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {                   

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        return expressionHandler;
    }
}
```

Whit all this now you can add:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_SUPER_USER')")
```

To validate the access regarding of the user role.